# How Can get the collection catalog_product_entity_tier_price

Tags: magento2, collection

I want to get the collection of this table how can I do it???

`catalog_product_entity_tier_price`

Comment: You want specific product Tier prices?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getProductCollectionTot() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_index_price as price_index', 'e.entity_id = price_index.entity_id');    // Add this join statement
        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier', 'price_index.entity_id = tier.entity_id');

        $collection->addFinalPrice()
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->getSelect()
            ->where('tier.all_groups = 0')
            ->where('price_index.Tier_price < price_index.price');

        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend :)